# Dynamic id with two variables

Tags: jquery, jsp

I want to do something like-

```
for(var i=0; i < count;i++) {
    $('#radio_'+i).click(function() {
       for(var j=0;j < count1;j++) {
          alert ($('#price_'+i+'_'+j).val());
       }
    })
}
```

But alert is coming **"undefiend"**.

i want to make id 'price_i_j' dynamic.

Comment: I'm sorry, what is it you're asking? I'm not exactly certain, and most people here probably aren't either. Unless I'm an idiot. Which is likely.

Comment: Can you show the markup as well?

Comment: try alert($('#wd_markup_'+i+'_'+j).length) and see if elements exist

Comment: you have wrapped the `click` event in a `loop` , i am not sure wat you want to do.Also while coding you should be conscious on terminators `;(semicolon)` while coding

Comment: One more thing try using `console.log()` to test data on developer tool of browser, this will give you more control in case of object, array , json etc than `alert`

Answer (score 0):

The alert **undefined** comes when the id is not find.
You should debug the code.
First `alert($('#wd_markup_'+i+'_'+j));` and check whether it is present or not. and after that check error console of browser, is there any error or not.

Comment: when i put #wd_markup_0_'+j it works fine but when i replace 0 with a variable it gives 'undefined'

Answer (score 0):

Do a check before giving alert

```
for(var i=0; i < channelCount;i++) {
    $('#radio_'+i).click(function() {
       for(var j=0;j < dopCount;j++) {
          if($('#price_'+i+'_'+j).length){
              alert ($('#price_'+i+'_'+j).val());
          }else{
              alert('#price_'+i+'_'+j + ' does not exist');
          }
       }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At the point each click function is called (when user clicks the #radio) i is equal to the count of the outer loop (+1), so if the count max was 2 then "i" would be 3 in each of click functions - this is why price is undefined as price_3 doesn't exist. What you need to do is get the value of i from the radio element something like the below. I've created a jsfiddle for you to see the below working.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    $('#radio_' + i).click(function() {
        var i = ($(this).attr("id").substr(6));
        $('[id^=price]').css("color", "black");
        for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            var s = '#price_' + i + '_' + j;
            console.log($(s).text());            
            $(s).css("color", "red");
        }
    })
}​
```

Example [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MvmFk)